# How to implement Java RMI to get non-connected client ip/hostnames

Tags: java, rmi

i have a RMI server and RMI client. If the client is running its version of RMI that i made and is ready to receive connections, how can i on the Server side get the IP/Hostname of the client even if the client is not connected to me?

I was thinking of creating a remote method that will call the client to send their IP/Hostname to my server side, but that would require me to know the Client IP/Hostname to be connected to inorder to invoke the method.

The purpose of this program is to create a monitoring program to monitor what are students doing on their labs, as a teacher.

Comment: "monitor students"?  What exactly are you needing to know?

Answer (score 1):

> how can i on the Server side get the IP/Hostname of the client even if the client is not connected to me?

That's a contradiction in terms. If there is no connection there is no current client. If you want a current client during a remote method invocation, see `RemoteServer.getClientHost()`. If you want that data other than during a remote method invocation, you can collect it during the remote method invocations, but you will have a hard time deciding when to remove a client, unless the client is obliged to call a `logout()` method or some such. You can clear the collection completely in an `Unreferenced.unreferenced()` method if that helps. But you need to get rid of the notion of 'connection' in RMI completely. There is basically no such thing. Connections exist for the duration of the call, and for whatever extra extent the implementation requires, but there is no way to get hold of them in either server or client, so you may as well design as though they don't exist, and as though the client doesn't exist except during a remote call.

*Or* use my Remote Session pattern, try Google.

Comment: Thanks your explanation cleared up some of the misconceptions i have in java RMI. I am now thinking of allowing the RMI Server to do a remote invocation from a range of user defined IP. This way if i am able to invoke the method , it means i can invoke future calls . Would this be doable?

Comment: @kyrogue I don't understand the question; I don't understand what the remote IP address has to do with monitoring what students are doing when they're not 'connected'; and it seems to me that you have 'client' and 'server' back to font. It is the server that receives connections, not the client. I think you need to sit down and redefine your problem more clearly.